# how to synchronize default volume with customized volume bar?

Tags: android

I am using a customized volume bar in my app so that when i increase or decrease from the default volume bar,my customized one should sync with the default automatically.Help me on this.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done by scaling my value with device volume level.Check this method.

```
private int setVolumeLevel(int actualvolume){ 
    int maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
    int scalevalue = maxVolume/mMaxvolLevel; 
    int mapedVolLevel = (actualvolume * scalevalue); 
    return mapedVolLevel; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) class.

Example available here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Volume/

Noone can really help you more than to tell you what you should look at. Especially when you don't include code.

Comment: I have seen this code already.But in my code i am  using any seekbar in one screen and another customized volumebar which will not have seekbar.Take a look at this                           private void setVolume(){
  mFinalVol = setVolumeLevel(mCount);
  VolumeActivity.mVolumeAdjust = mFinalVol;
  mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,VolumeActivity.mVolumeAdjust, 0); 
 }

Comment: private int setVolumeLevel(int actualvolume){ int maxVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); int scalevalue = maxVolume/mMaxvolLevel; int mapedVolLevel = (actualvolume * scalevalue); return mapedVolLevel; }These are the methods i used to set the volume for my customised Volume bar

Comment: In this code VolumeActicity is for volumebar with seekbar.I am using a static variable to use it in other videoplayer activity.Above code is Videoplayer activity's code